# Cuberankedmember getting wrong order

Tags: excel, powerpivot, olap-cube

I'm trying to create a top3 ranking from a data table varying metrics but each time I get the wrong order from the `cuberankedmember`, usually misplacing ranks `2` and `3`.

The data I'm mostly focused on is regarding sales revenue. Power pivot sums all sales by store, quite straight forward.

From this I use a cubeset formula that captures store name, filtered by a month and year, which the user types in as any day for the month, and set the measure which to sort by (NTS) (code 1).

The `cuberankedmember` selects the `cubeset` and defines the position (code `2`).

Then the cubevalue selects as members the `cuberankedmember`, filters once again month and year, then pulls in the measure (code `3`).

`E4` is the date

`Code1` (cell `C21`):

```
    =CUBESET("ThisWorkbookDataModel";
      "NONEMPTY([Store_Dict].[Nome_DSR].children,
      ([Calendar].[Year].[All].["&YEAR($E$4)&"],
      [Calendar].[Month Number].[All].["&MONTH($E$4)&"]))";
      "Ranking";
      2;
      "[Measures].[NTS]")`

`Code2` (cell `D22`):

   `=CUBERANKEDMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel";$C$21;1;"a")

`C21` is the `CUBESET` formula
```

`Code3`:

```
    CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel";
      $D22;
      "[Calendar].[Month Number].["&MONTH($E$4)&"]";
      "[Calendar].[Year].["&YEAR($E$4)&"]";
      "[Measures].[NTS]")
```

Actual Result:

```
Ranking    Store    NTS

1    a       606 

2    c       425 

3    b       428
```

Expected result:

```
Ranking  Store      NTS

1    a       606 

2    b       428 

3    c       425
```

Comment: Even I face the same problem. It is strange that a Pivot Table is able to do it correctly, but not the CUBEFORMULAS. I finally settled for always getting it out alphabetically, since that is something I can work with. I did notice that you are not passing a measure to the second argument of the nonempty() function. It is good practice to pass a measure (maybe pass the one you want to sort by).